# passing message from property file to javascript in struts

Tags: javascript, tags, struts, javabeans

I have a properties file which contains the label of a button
**Message.properties**

```
login.button.validate=Validate
login.button.cancel=Cancel
```

In struts, I can read the properties file as follow:

```
<bean:message key=login.button.validate />
```

Is there a way to use this tag  in javascript ?

```
<button id="btn" type="button" value=""></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = '<bean:message key="login.button.validate" />';
</script>
```

or just use the key of the message

```
document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = 'login.button.validate';
```

Comment: The same way you do now, assuming the "JavaScript" file (which you show as an HTML file with embedded JS) is actually a JSP file. Obviously not the latter way.

Comment: The first code return <bean:message key="login.button.validate" /> as the label of the button and this is not what I expect. How can I return the message instead of the tag ?

Comment: Put it in a JSP so it's evaluated on the server.